# Cocos2d individual buttons placement

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I paid a Freelancer to make a game for me. I am experienced in normal Ojct-C and storyboards but not coco2sd. He made a menu for when the game is over. 3 Buttons (Social media sharing buttons) and 1 replay button. I'm trying to move the social media buttons upward (to make space for iads) but keep the replay button at the same place. Here the code:

```
-(void)createMenu
{
btnNextpeer=newButtonPosA(@"next", POS_BTN_NEXT, self, @selector(onNextpeerClicked:), true, RATIO_Y, F_BTN_SCALE);
btnEM=newButtonPosA(@"em", POS_BTN_EM, self, @selector(onClickEM:), false, RATIO_Y, F_BTN_SCALE);
btnFB=newButtonPosA(@"fb", POS_BTN_FB, self, @selector(onClickFB:), false, RATIO_Y, F_BTN_SCALE);
btnTW=newButtonPosA(@"tw", POS_BTN_TW, self, @selector(onClickTW:),false, RATIO_Y, F_BTN_SCALE);
btnGC=newButtonPosA(@"gc", POS_BTN_GC, self, @selector(onClickGC:), true, RATIO_Y, F_BTN_SCALE);
btnRestart=newButtonPosA(@"restart", POS_BTN_RESTART, self, @selector(onClickRestart:), false, RATIO_Y, 1.0);

menu=[CCMenu menuWithItems:btnNextpeer,btnEM,btnFB,btnTW,btnGC,btnRestart, nil];
[menu setPosition:ccp(0,30)];
[self addChild:menu z:Z_BTN];
[self showButtons:false];
}
```

(0,0) is the default position. I want the Social medias buttons to be at (0,30) but the replay at (0,0).

Here's what i tried to do to move the replay button to (0,0):

```
menu=[CCMenu menuWithItems:btnNextpeer,btnEM,btnFB,btnTW,btnGC,btnRestart, nil];
[btnRestart setPosition:ccp(0, 100)];
[menu setPosition:ccp(0,30)];
[self addChild:menu z:Z_BTN];
[self showButtons:false];
```

When i added that simple line of code, the Replay button disappeared. 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example from a game. GETextMenuItem is one of my creatures, basically it extends CCMenuItemLabel and adds long touch (to show a tooltip), pre-canned fonts and font sizes for the label and tooltip, and some behaviour to oversize slightly during the touch. But here it is :

```
CGSize dims = CGSizeMake(deviceOffset(230), deviceOffset(40));

// a bunch of other menu items before 

GETextMenuItem *fx = [GETextMenuItem textMenuItemWithText:@"FX volume"
                                               dimensions:dims
                                                alignment:kCCTextAlignmentLeft
                                                     font:kMPAmenuFont
                                                 fontSize:deviceFontSize(16)
                                                    color:ccWHITE
                                                   target:nil selector:nil];
fx.toolTip = @"Adjusts the sound effects volume from mute to the current master volume.";

GETextMenuItem *music = [GETextMenuItem textMenuItemWithText:@"Music volume"
                                                  dimensions:dims
                                                   alignment:kCCTextAlignmentLeft
                                                        font:kMPAmenuFont
                                                    fontSize:deviceFontSize(16)
                                                       color:ccWHITE
                                                      target:nil selector:nil];
music.toolTip = @"Adjusts the music setting volume from mute to the current master volume.";

CCMenu *labelMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:showDialogs, showHelp, showConfirmation, master, fx, music, nil];

float hOffs = -kScreenWidth / 2 + dims.width / 2 + _leftMargin;

showDialogs.position      = ccp(hOffs, kScreenHeight / 2 - _topMargin);
showHelp.position         = ccp(hOffs, kScreenHeight / 2 - _topMargin - 1 * _toggleMenuSpacing);
showConfirmation.position = ccp(hOffs, kScreenHeight / 2 - _topMargin - 2 * _toggleMenuSpacing);
master.position           = ccp(hOffs, kScreenHeight / 2 - _topMargin - 3 * _toggleMenuSpacing);
fx.position               = ccp(hOffs, kScreenHeight / 2 - _topMargin - 4 * _toggleMenuSpacing);
music.position            = ccp(hOffs, kScreenHeight / 2 - _topMargin - 5 * _toggleMenuSpacing);

labelMenu.position = ccp(0, 0);
[self addChild:labelMenu];
```

so, i place the menu midscreen, and place each button at _leftMargin from the left of the screen, and _topMargin down from the top. For this 'menu' i dont use any target, the only point of doing this a menu was to get tooltips (help texts) when a label is pressed.  This is how it comes out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't (freely) reposition individual items in a menu. Instead put each item in its own menu, then you are free to position each menu individually by altering the menu's position (as opposed to the menu's item).

Comment: hmmm ... i place menu item's positions inside a ccmenu  pretty much for every menu scene i have (cocos2d 2.1). I first set the menu item's relative position inside the menu, then set the menu position appropriately.

Comment: maybe that was fixed, i remember any item.position change messed up touch detection

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Could you write an answer explaining in details please?